# How can I connect to Google Drive using a login password?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

The task is following.
Our user enters a google drive login password on our site and get access to his files on a google drive. Later some files may be uploaded to my server.
Is it possible?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is Client login, google shut down client login in 2015. So the answer is you cant.

In order to access google APIs you need to use [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and have a user consent to your application accessing their data.

Once the user has authorized your application you will be able to retrieve something called an access token this is a bearer token which grants your application access to the data for one hour.  All calls to the api must include an authorization header with this bearer token

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Depending upon which language your using i recommend looking for a client library in that language.  It will make authorization easer.